# Does the size of a table impact the performance of insert query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I need to improve performance of `INSERT INTO` query to a table which has 1 billion rows. This table contains a clustered index primary key.

One suggestion is to reduce the table data by deleting (copying to archive table) old records and keep most recent records in the table. This will reduce data from 1 billion to 2 million. Will this approach increase data write process?

Are there any other way to increase record insert process?

Note: this `INSERT INTO` query is in a complex stored procedure and the execution plan points to this `INSERT` statement taking a certain amount of time.

Comment: When inserted new rows, are they always ascending on the Clustered Index? Is there *only* a clustered index on the table, or are there other indexes?

Comment: There are two non-clustered indexes and disabling them before the insertion improved the performance but again rebuilding those two indexes again takes time. (May be we can rebuild indexes in off peak time which will not effect the business)

Comment: Clustered index is an auto increment INT

Comment: Are there foreign keys that references this table?

Comment: Yes. There's a one foreign key at the moment. Can a FK  impact the data insert ?

Comment: No, FK will not permit you to use TRUNCATE solution by Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 5):

Simplistically, reducing the size of the table will not have much impact on performance.  There are some cases where it could make a difference.

If the clustered index primary key is not ordered, then you have a fragmentation problem.  That means that inserts are likely to be splitting pages and rewriting them.

The "good" news is that in the existing table, your pages are probably already fragmented, so you probably have few full pages.  So splitting is less likely.  This is "good" in quotes because it means that you have lots of wasted space, which is inefficient for queries.

If you remove the excess rows and compact (defrag) the table, then you will have some advantages.  The biggest is that the data will probably fit into memory -- a big performance advantage.

I would recommend that you fix the table because the extra rows are probably hurting *query* performance.  Given the volume of data, I would suggest a truncate/re-insert approach:

```
select t.*
into temp_t
from t
where <rows to keep logic here>;

truncate table t;   -- be sure you have a backup!

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

This will be much faster than trying to delete 99.9% of the rows (unless you happen to have a partitioned table where you can simply drop partitions).

If you want to keep the old data, you might find a way to *partition* the table.  Of course, your queries would have to use the partitioning key to access the "valid" rows rather than the archive.

Comment: >>>If you want to keep the old data, you might find a way to partition the table<<< It will certainly DECREASE insert speed

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I'm not aware of table defragment in SQL server but I will give a try.

Comment: @sepupic . . . Partitioning the data should not decrease `insert` speed, particularly if all new records are simply going into the "active" partition.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff It seems that you never worked with partitioned tables. First of all there is a limitation that identity cannot be part of the partition key. I refactored problematic table and used sequence to generate the values and even if all the inserts have evre increasing values in id that was partition key there was noticible decrease of insert speed

Comment: ...And of course there is no way to use the same table beacuse you just cannot truncate it with FK that referencing it, then you cannot even insert with set identity_insert on without having an additional SORT, even if you have all your rows ordered by PK. This means downtime and you should use another table, bettere refactored without identity, to move the data you want to save, renaming it when done and drop of original table. And moving new rows that were inserted while you was moving your data is also problematic in highly loaded OLTP database